# Comparing the selected code with ASTNode

Tags: java

I have done a plugin in eclipse helios for parsing (AST) and comparing code. First I parse the code and keep the MethodDeclaration node. Then I select a method from the code to compare with the methods of the node.

I save the code in `SelectedText selectedText` and the node in `MethodDeclaration method`.

How can I compare this two variables to know if they are holding the same code??? I have done the next code but it doesn't work:

```
for (MethodDeclaration method : visitor.getMethods()) {                       
          if(selectedText.getSelectedText().equals(method.toString())){
              MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "COMPARISON", "GOOD");                 
          }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the selected code into an AST as well; otherwise simple differences in white space like `a=0` and `a = 0` would be different.

Look at the source code for the Java editor, it should be possible to ask it for the AST node of the currently selected method.